# How can I fix Visual Studio 2015 exception Microsoft.vshup.server.httphostx64.exe has stopped working when run project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio Community 2015 and I created a project, but when I run the project I get this exception:

> Microsoft.vshup.server.httphostx64.exe has stopped working

I am using Windows 8.

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Do your event logs provide anything relevant?  Should probably post those if so, or the ActivityLog.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Now I install windows 10 and reinstall visual studio 2015 and fixed this exception

Comment: Have tried a lot of actions described above.
In my case helped simple renaming of the VsHub folder like previously has been suggested. Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 17):

This is a bit late, but for everyone else struggling with this, in my case this issue was solved after deleting Webcompanion from Lavasoft and removing all register entries containing Lavasoft
This issue came up using VS2015 Community with Win8.1

Comment: Confirmed! Got this problem after installing nmap portscanner and gui, which seemed to chuck Lavasoft stuff onto my system too.

Comment: Confirmed! And I also got problems creating a new SQL Server database using Migrations. Somehow, the Lavasoft software got in the way there as well. I got the Lavasoft Web Companion when installing k-lite codec pack. There was a screen during the install that mentioned it, but I missed it. Fortunately, Web Companions UnInstall worked like a charm, so my problems are over.

Comment: This fixed it for me. (VS2015 on WIn10). Been at this for weeks, thanks you!

Comment: Uninstalled Webcompanion and it worked perfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

I searched the solution for hours in order to remove this error! The Windows updates changed nothing for me. The best way to get rid of this error is to go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared` and delete or rename the folder `VSHub`. Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Fixed the problem for me, and I haven't noticed any side-effects so far.  I renamed the folder instead of deleting it.

Comment: This is a straight and hard solution I like.

Answer (score 3):

We have finally produced a patch for this specific problem with VSHub crashing while debugging. There may be other issues with VS2015 and this patch doesn't solve all of them, but it is aimed directly at this problem. Please give it a try.

The patch is available via http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3090034.

Note: This patch will not be necessary on systems that have installed any of the future quarterly updates to Visual Studio 2015 RTM. Quarterly updates are expected to start shipping in the future and will have this fix along with other changes. We much prefer that you use a quarterly update rather than single patches like the one I referenced. Until quarterly updates are available, however, you'll need to use this patch.

Comment: I've the latest VS2015 Pro (Windows 8.1)  and I still have the same problem. Everything is at latest update. Allen, could you possible explain what this **vshub** is for at all?

Comment: Still happens in VS2015CE, June 2016, Win10

Comment: Uninstalling Webcompanion by Lavasoft solved the problem; see Harm's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this?

- Stop Visual Studio if started
- rename Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe to 
  Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe.bak
- Create a copy of Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe and rename it
  Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe
- Re-start Visual Studio

http://thomas-barthelemy.github.io/2015/05/01/visual-studio-vshub/

Comment: I try this solution but not fixed exception

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar issue.

I renamed folder named VsHub to VsHub1 (Renamed to anything)

Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared

Now its working

i need to find whether it is affecting at any other place

Answer (score 1):

I soled the problem my installing
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49138
twice (the second time choose "repair" option).

Make sure the VS is close and VSHub is not running in Task manager

Answer (score 1):

Please try this if you want to Fix this, it's worked for me:

`Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe has stopped working`

Use This Root to locate your Error : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\1.0.0.0`

[image]

- Close your visual studio 2015 (if Open / started)
- **End this process from Task Manager** see the image above
- Go to this Path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\` and Find "VsHub" and rename it. That is !! ** you are DONE !**.

This Help me to get Rid of the Problem as Fast and Possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just Uninstall WebCompanion Lavasoft software

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue due to corrupted drivers but it happened while debugging, I fixed it by 
unchecking `"use hardware graphic acceleration "` from `Tools > options > environment`
and followed the steps in this post:

https://thomas-barthelemy.github.io/2015/05/01/visual-studio-vshub/

Navigate to

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\1.0.0.0"

- Stop Visual Studio if started
- rename Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe to Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe.bak
- Create a copy of Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe and rename it Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe
- Re-start Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

One fast thing to try, it helped one other guy with the same issue, he posted on official microsoft help forum (when I myself googled it I got your topic and 2 from official MS help forum as top hits)
AND helped me with also the same issue.

Most likely its some unwanted stuff on your PC, just use AdwCleaner or smth like that, I used that, the other guy also did some deleting though not sure if with the same soft.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution-
The crashing file is located in the following folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\1.0.0.0
It seems that the x86 version of the file does not have the same issue, so a simple fix, until a better one is officially published by Microsoft:

- Stop Visual Studio if started rename
- Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe to
- Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe.bak Create a copy of
- Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe and rename it
- Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe Re-start Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and resolved it by removing the VsHub directory at below location.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\

this is the simplest way the fix the problem, VS will recreate the directory on it need.