# Getting ScriptedSandbox64.exe_190926_123150 and Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe_190926_123132 dump files whenever I run my c# application

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, thread-safety, sandbox

I have a multithreaded application . Whenever I am running the source code in the Debug environment , I get the dump files for Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe_190926_123132 and ScriptedSandbox64.exe_190926_105255 getting generated by the procDump .

I am not able to figure it out what to do . Is there any way , we can analyze through the Windbg by providing the symbols file ?

Comment: Do you have any code to let us to test it?

Comment: This was happening whenever I was starting my application in debug mode . I followed the following "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634342/how-can-i-fix-visual-studio-2015-exception-microsoft-vshup-server-httphostx64-ex" and "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071997/scriptedsandbox64-exe-has-stopped-working-visual-studio-2015". I was able to resolve the issue . But still I am beginner in case I need to analyze the issue through windbg . Any help for analyzing dump file will be highly appreciated.